# Setting Axis to Time using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have spent some time researching this but no idea if I am on the right track of not so thought I would ask for help.

I have a graph in access that changes depending on what option is selected from a drop down menu - One option involves HH:NN:SS, so I need to change the format of the graph to allow it as at the moment its showing as total number of seconds instead.

**Code:**

```
ElseIf MetricList = "Telephony - Busy Time" Then
TrendGraph.RowSource = "SELECT (Format([WC_Date],'yy  ww')) AS Week, tbl_Genesys_Weekly.Field5, Sum(tbl_Genesys_Weekly.Field44) AS SumOfField44 FROM tbl_Genesys_Weekly GROUP BY (Format([WC_Date],'yy  ww')), tbl_Genesys_Weekly.Field5 HAVING (((tbl_Genesys_Weekly.Field5)='User'));"
```

**I have been trying:**
Trendgraph.axis but this does not bring up any property fields so can assume I am completely wrong at this stage

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your minute count:

```
Sum(tbl_Genesys_Weekly.Field44)
```

you can get a time value with *TimeSerial*:

```
TimeSerial(0, Sum(tbl_Genesys_Weekly.Field44), 0)
```

and then format this as you like, for example:

```
Format(TimeSerial(0, Sum(tbl_Genesys_Weekly.Field44), 0), "hh:nn:ss")
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment - VBA doesn't appear to like this: "HH:NN:SS" (Syntax Error)

Comment: Sorry, it is _TimeSerial_. Corrected.